How to use the Livewire component nested in a livewire form
I have a form which has dynamic selects, I want to separate these selects into another livewire component, so as not to reprogram them in each form, but I don't know how to validate them and obtain their values from the parent livewire component, how could I do the selects component to use them in other livewire forms?
I have read the documentation and it can be bound with the parent component, but it only allows one property and in these selects I have 3 properties (Country, State and City) these are the selects:
<div class="col-4">
    <x-adminlte-input type="text" wire:model.live='employeeForm.employee_code' name="employeeForm.employee_code" label="Codigo de empleado" />
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <x-adminlte-select wire:model.live='employeeForm.team_id' name="employeeForm.team_id" label="Equipo:">
        <x-adminlte-options :options='$employeeForm->teams' empty-option="Seleciona un equipo..." />
    </x-adminlte-select>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <x-adminlte-select wire:model.live='employeeForm.company_id' name="employeeForm.company_id" label="Empresa:">
        <x-adminlte-options :options='$employeeForm->companies' empty-option="Seleciona una empresa..." />
    </x-adminlte-select>
</div>

My component code:
class CreateEmployeeForm extends Component
{
    public EmployeeForm $employeeForm;

    public $age = 0;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->employeeForm->init();
    }

    public function updatedEmployeeFormCountryId($value)
    {
        $this->employeeForm->updateStates($value);
    }
    public function updatedEmployeeFormstateId($value)
    {
        $this->employeeForm->updateCities($value);
    }
    public function updatedEmployeeFormBirthDate($value)
    {
        $this->age = Carbon::parse($value)->diff(now())->y;
    }
    public function updatedEmployeeFormCompanyId($value)
    {
        $this->employeeForm->updateCompanyAssigment($value);
    }
    public function updatedEmployeeFormDepartamentId($value)
    {
        $this->employeeForm->updateJobPositions($value);
    }
    public function save()
    {
        $this->employeeForm->store();
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-employee-form');
    }
}

My EmployeeForm Code:
public function updateStates($citySelectedId)
{
    $this->states = Country::find($citySelectedId)?->states()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    $this->reset(['state_id', 'city_id']);
}

public function updateCities($stateSelectedId)
{
    $this->cities = State::find($stateSelectedId)?->cities()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    $this->reset(['city_id']);
}

public function updateCompanyAssigment($companySelectedId)
{
    $company = app(CompanyRepository::class)->find($companySelectedId);
    $this->departaments = $company?->departaments()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    $this->areas = $company?->areas()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    $this->payRolls = $company?->payRolles()->get()->pluck('code', 'id')->all();
    $this->reset(['area_id', 'payroll_id', 'departanment_id']);
}

public function updateJobPositions($departamentSelectedId)
{
    $this->jobPositions = Departament::find($departamentSelectedId)?->jobPositions()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
}

